# How to change scripting runtime to 4.7.2 in Unity 2019.1.0f2? It is by default targeting 4.7.1

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Currently I am using Unity 2019.1.0f2 and from the editor when I create a new Script, its Script Runtime targets .NET 4.7.1. In my machine, I am using .NET 4.7.2 with Visual Studion 2019. So when I try to build the project in Visual Studio, the project fails to load asking me to either install 4.7.1 or fallback to 4.6. This is rather annoying. How can the target be changed from the Editor without doing any config changes in Visual Studio. TIA